# Groovy Time durations

Tags: datetime, groovy

I'm trying to get the difference between 2 dates in days, hours, and seconds:

```
import groovy.time.*

Date now = new Date()

// Using deprecated constructor just for this example
Date newYearsDay2000 = new Date(2000, 0, 1)

use (TimeCategory) {
    now - newYearsDay2000
}
```

This prints:

> -690023 days, -14 hours, -38 minutes, -27.182 seconds

Which is obviously nothing like the difference between today's date and 2000/1/1, where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be an issue with the deprecated constructor?

If you use Calendar ([and the Groovy updated method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Calendar.html#updated%28java.util.Map%29)) to create the `newYearsDay2000` var, you get:

```
import groovy.time.*
import static java.util.Calendar.*

Date now = new Date()
// Use the static imported Calendar class
Date newYearsDay2000 = instance.updated( year:2000, month:JANUARY, day:1 ).time

use( TimeCategory ) {
    now - newYearsDay2000
}
```

which gives the result:

```
3925 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59.999 seconds
```

---

**Edit**

Yeah, the [JavaDoc for Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html?is-external=true) shows that constructor with the comment:

> Date(int year, int month, int date)
>
> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).

Which leads me to believe that:

```
Date newYearsDay2000 = new Date(2000, 0, 1)
```

Is actualy creating the Date for new Years Day in the year **3900**

Answer (score 1):

[Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29)
Parameters:
    year - the year minus 1900.